# Installing Muse Plugins Fx On Audacity

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, audacity, sfx, plug-ins

I want to install the [Muse Hub plugin suite](https://plugins.audacityteam.org/realtime-effects/plugin-suites#muse-fx) specifically for noise filtering and other real time effects, but as a beginner I can't really figure it out and I didn't find any useful tutorials that show how.
I also installed [Muse Hub](https://www.musehub.com/) but it only had sounds not the plugins for Audacity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's a basic customer support question, better addressed to the manufacturer/developer.

Comment: I'm not sure about that hub, anyway - just looks like a waste of background computer resources to me. But anyway, Tetsujin is right, if it's not working properly, you need to ask _them_.

Answer (score 1):

On the page [Muse Hub plugin suite](https://plugins.audacityteam.org/realtime-effects/plugin-suites#muse-fx) from your question there is a link to another free plugin suite, [IEM Plugin Suite](https://plugins.iem.at/).

I will explain how to install particularly version [1.13.0 for Windows](https://users.iem.at/holzmueller/IEM-Audioplugins/IEMPluginSuite/v1.13.0/IEMPluginSuite_v1.13.0_x64.zip), because with the current version (1.14.0) I had problems.

The downloaded [`IEMPluginSuite_v1.13.0_x64.zip`](https://users.iem.at/holzmueller/IEM-Audioplugins/IEMPluginSuite/v1.13.0/IEMPluginSuite_v1.13.0_x64.zip) file contains 2 folders:

- `VST2`, which containing all VST2 plugins, and
- `VST3`, containing all VST3 plugins.

In both that folders, there is only one folder – its name is `IEM`.

Copy one or both of these `IEM` folders as a whole to their appropriate directories:

- For **VST2** plugins there is *no required special directory.*

  - If you already have some VST2 plugins, copy the `IEM` folder to the same place,
  - otherwise create a new folder for them, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Common Files\VST2\`
- **VST3** plugins must be placed into their **required** directory, which is

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Common Files\VST3\
  ```

There is no need to install (i.e. to copy) *both* VST2 and VST3 plugins if you will use them only in Audacity (or other DAW which supports both standards).

Audacity (and most DAWs) is able to find such “installed” plugins automatically, but in the case of need you may manually scan for them:

- **Tools ⇾ Plugin Manager,** and then click on the “**Rescan**” button.